# Why are cassette tapes considered analogue?

Tags: analog

As far as I can tell, the cassette ribbon can only have the magnetic particles arranged in 2 directions, making it digital. So why are they called analogue? Is this a sort of gray area?

Comment: can it? have you told magnitism that

Comment: individual film grains can be clear or opaque, and light at some level is quantum, yet we still refer to film photography as analog because it's not _discrete_. Thus, even if tapes _were_ only N+S at full Gauss, unless we counted each "magnet" we cannot 100% reproduce the signal since the audio would be an averaging of the indeterminate poles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magnetism is traditionally referred to as having North and South polarisation (two directions). Magnetism however is a vector which has direction and magnitude.

One area could be perfectly aligned with "N" and say  1mT, another could be perfectly aligned with 0.5mT.

Likewise the field could be aligned +45deg from N

By varying the field intensity when the magnetic tape is recorded, the magnitude of the analogue data can be superimposed

[image]

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Audio/bias.html#c4

Comment: No need to be crusty, there are plenty of digital magnetic devices, and I thought this was one of them. Here's a good visualization of the non- digital nature of cassettes. http://reel2reeltexas.com/vinAd49MakingMagRecVisable.jpg

Comment: I wasn't being crusty oO I just stated magnetism is a vector and thus analogue information can be stored

Comment: No, this graphic post was good, but your other comment was dumb. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: @noobboob Why so rude?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that magnetic particles have only two possible orientations (which is essentially false in the first place) make magnetism as much digital as electrons, which have only two possible spins (if my memory serves me right).

Joke aside, what makes magnetism analogue is that the stored information is a **linear** — as opposed to digitized — response, in the mathematical sense of the term, to the input signal. A digital signal is quantized first using an analogue-to-digital conversion, which causes its digital representation to fit a **finite** amount of states (e.g. \$ 2^{16} \$ or \$ 2^{24} \$), as opposed to a (theoretically maybe) **infinite** number of states for analogue systems. As a result, digitized signals are **non linear** representations of the initial signal. For example, current, also, may have only two (symbolic) polarities (plus or minus) but it can vary linearly in amplitude between two given values, whereas if it were digital it could only vary in steps.

Think of analogue as a linear representation and digital as non-linear. This is my non-scientific definition of the differences between analogue and digital.

Comment: There are plenty of digital magnetic storage devices, I assumed audio cassettes were one of them.

Comment: Well, usage is one thing. The fact that tapes *can* be used to store digital information doesn't mean they digitize the information they store.

Comment: Wouldn't that make everything stored as analogue? A CD would be analogue because the pits aren't exactly the same size, but it meets the logical threshold and becomes digital.

Comment: I think you are mixing up some different ideas:  An _analog_ signal is represented by some physical variable (current, voltage, frequency,...).  A _sampled_ signal has a value that only changes at regular, discrete instants in time.  A _quantized_ signal has only a finite number of possible values.  A signal can be sampled and quantized and still be analog; OR, it can be _encoded_ as a sequence of numbers, and thereby become a _digital signal_.  I won't say what _linear_ means 'cause I'm not a mathematician, and I'm not sure I would get it right.

Comment: That would be oversimplifying how a CDROM — or any storage media — works. The pit length doesn't makes a CD analogue because its digital nature is made from the presence or the absence of a pit, i.e. binary information.

Comment: @jameslarge I tried to be extremely careful choosing my terms to precisely avoid confusion. Not that easy when you intuitively know the difference but need the proper terms to make it understood, right? I'll try to rephrase that part a bit.

Comment: @noobboob There can be many layers of meaning in a signal.  All recordings _are_ analog at the _lowest_ level---the output from the photo diode in a CD player is a continuously varying voltage; but there are many layers of meaning.  At a higher level the CD signal is interpreted as a sequence of rising and falling edges, and at a higher level still, as a sequence of bits, from which a higher level extracts _frames_ of  bytes and words.  At some highest level (I don't know how many layers there really are) it is interpreted as samples in a digitized, stereo, audio stream.

Answer (score -3):

as you said its more like in grey area. if you record an audio it will fall in to analogue because you not doing any encoding or decoding but if you use this as a digital data storage like  in the late 1970s audio cassettes are used as digital data storage[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_cassettes).

[wikipedia ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_cassettes)

[how audio recording is done](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Audio/tape.html#c1)

Comment: Thanks, I know magnetic storage CAN be used for digital data, but I was mistaken to think the audio cassettes used that method.